# Using R, Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : too many SQL variables

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf

I uses `sqldf`package to make SQLite database, my matrix dimension is 2880x1951. I write the table on the SQLite database, unfortunately it asks `Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : too many SQL variables`. I read from SQlite website if the limitation of number variables use is limited to 999. Is there a simple way to increase the value of this?

Here is my syntax:

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="xxx.sqlite") 
bunch_vis <- read.csv("xxx.csv")  
dbWriteTable(db, name = "xxx", value = xxx,
row.names = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

and the output:

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : too many SQL variables
```